# Create copy+pastable PDFs from scans

Tags: linux, pdf, ocr

I have PDF files which get created from a scanner. The PDFs only contain images.

Up to now you can't copy+paste the text if you look at the PDF with Acrobat or an other PDF viewer.

Needed features:

- OCR: read text from the images
- Annotate the PDF and create a hidden overlay to make text copy and pastable.
- Processing of one page should not last longer then 20 seconds
- Command-line and/or API, no GUI needed

Optional:

- If there is an API, Python bindings would be nice

I only need to support Linux, no other operating system. Open source preferred, but commercial software recommendations are valid answers, too.

Answer (score 2):

The solution you want can be found at our sister site: [how to OCR a pdf file and get the text stored within pdf?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/301318/209279) Quoting [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/421686/209279):

> Best and easyest way out there is to use `pypdfocr` it doesn't change the pdf. [pypdfocr is a python module link here.](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypdfocr)
>
> ```
> pypdfocr your_document.pdf
> ```
>
> At the end you will have another `your_document_ocr.pdf` the way you want it with searchable text. The app doesn't change the quality of the image. Increases the size of the file a bit by adding the overlay text.
>
> I think the command is pretty easy that it doesn't need any GUI.
>   Maybe installing pypdfocr is a bit more verbose:
>
> ```
> sudo dnf -y install tesseract 
> pip install pypdfocr
> ```

I can't tell about processing time, and certainly you'll need a separate tool to create the annotations – but all your other requirements should be perfectly met:

- **OCR:** Yes.
- **open source:** Yes.
- **command line, no GUI needed:** Yes.
- **Support Linux:** Yes.
- **Python bindings:** Well, it's plain Python (except for calling to Tesseract).

Alternatively, working the same way, there's another Python module called **[ocrmypdf](https://pypi.org/project/ocrmypdf/4.1.4/)**. This also uses Tesseract for the OCR process.

A third candidate would be **[pdfsandwich](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsandwich/)** – but that comes without the Python component.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use **Adobe's Creative Cloud - All Apps**
https://www.adobe.com/creativecloud/plans.html

- Monthly subscription - cancel anytime.
- OCR - quality depends on the dots per inch scan.
  Readability and quality of scanned item.
- Pasteable text - yes.
- Editable original text - yes.
- Notation - Yes

Unfortunately I can not answer for the following:

- Command Line and or API.

From my research Adobe will work on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [**Tesseract**](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract), open source OCR software.

It comes with a command line program and there are Python bindings as well.
Packages available in your Linux distro.

```
apt-get install tesseract-ocr
#convert pdf to scans.tiff
tesseract scans.tiff out pdf
```

- ✓ OCR
- ✓ searchable PDF output
- ✓ open source
- ✓ fast enough (v3 faster than v4 though)
- ✓ command-line and/or API
- ✓ works on Linux
- ✓ python bindings

Comment: Unfortunately tesseract can't take a PDF (containing for example 5 scanned pages) and output a PDF with hidden text annotations. At least I could not find a way to do it.

Comment: I think the missing step is that you'd need to first convert the PDF file to a multipage TIFF image, which you then pass as input to tesseract.

Answer (score 0):

This Python3 based tool does have all features: https://pypi.org/project/ocrmypdf/

- OCR: yes
- Annotate the PDF and create a hidden overlay to make text copy and pastable: yes
- Processing of one page should not last longer then 20 seconds: yes
- Command-line and/or API, no GUI needed: yes
- If there is an API, Python bindings would be nice: yes